# Formatting Data in Textbox to $###,###,###,##0.00

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a textbox  where I always want data in $###,###,###,##0.00 format (like $25.00 ). Now on typing some data i want to get the same format . For ex if i type 25 it should convert to $25.00 and if i input 'as23afs' (characters) it should convert to $0.00 . How can i do it?  Please suggest a solution. If I can make use of Regular expressions how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at those plugins:

1. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
2. http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/
3. http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: Can i do like <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod(
        "australianDate",
        function(value, element) {
            // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
            return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
        },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
    );

    $('#myForm')
        .validate({
            rules :
                myDate : {
                    australianDate : true
                }
        })
    ;
});            
</script>
. Pls give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue now i fixed that by set the textbox custom Format:
use this code in KeyPress Event   :

```
 private void yourtextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '$') // 8 is back space
        {

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // 13 is Enter
            {
                yourtextbox.Text = string.Format("${0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(yourtextbox.Text));
            }
        }

    }
```

Now your Textbox accept only numbers and ',' and '$'

now if you input 'as23afs' (characters) it should convert to $0.00 .
use this code :

```
yourtextbox.Text = double.Parse("0").ToString("N2");//"N2" to show 00 after ','.
```

i think that's all i hope this code help everyone looking for currency Format in textbox .

so the complete code should be like that :

```
     public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            yourtextbox.Text = double.Parse("0").ToString("N2");//"N2" to show 00 after ','
        }



     private void yourtextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '$') // 8 is back space
        {

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // 13 is Enter
            {
                yourtextbox.Text = string.Format("${0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(yourtextbox.Text));
            }
        }

    }
```