# Want to display the numbers which i enter, with comma seperated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox control in my mvc application. I will be entering amount in that textbox at runtime. When i enter the amount, it should be displayed with comma seperated numbers. How to accomplish this?

Thanks 
Manikandan

Comment: can you elaborate your question please. You mean instead of decimal point you want to have comma?

Comment: @Anna.P : I will be entering numbers at runtime into that textbox control. I need to write a script to display the numbers with comma seperated.

Comment: you mean you will enter 1234 and it should display 1,2,3,4. Am i right

Comment: @Anna.P : Not exactly. If i enter 1234, it should be 1,234.. like that...

Comment: You have to tell us a language and framework. Use the tags for this. The only tag you have now is "numbers", which is completely useless.

Comment: first the C# and MVC has no real or absolute relation to that that it is more related to HTML and JavaScript, you can implement it from scratch if you have good knowledge of javascript or use a famous library like jquery.

Comment: @Ahmedsafan : Can you help me get around it?

Comment: i can give you tips, really I'm fighting with C++, look at this question you will find good solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929814/formatting-data-in-textbox-to-0-00

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook the onKeyUp javascript event on client side, and change the text box text on the fly. I am sure you can find many examples of that if you search.