# How to set the format and allowed characters of textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and I want to set the format into just like this 00-000

How to do that?

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: see this link it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929814/formatting-data-in-textbox-to-0-00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jQuery to mask the input and validate the input is what you want. In this case numbers.

One such plugin is http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

You can mask inputs with

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

There's also a demo on that page.